# How do I add a Class on a page targeting a specific URL via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I add a Class on a page targeting a specific URL via jQuery?

Comment: Please explain your question in a bit more detail

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a class to a link that goes to example.com but add a different class to a link that goes to other-example.com?

Comment: My apologies for unclear post, I want to target a [age with it's URL the add a class for the page using jquery. e.g if the URL is: example.com/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1 then add CSS class on that page maybe append on existing class...

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you want to add a link to all anchor tags that have a specific href value?

You can filter your `a` tag matches by the `href` attribute using the following:

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').addClass("className");
```

Comment: +1 Consider using `^=` instead *if* you only want to match on the host, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/sKsLv/1/

Comment: thanks guys, i see what the script above does but it's not want i want. I want to attach classname on body tag when specific page with it's unique URL/web address add . e.g opened http://www.example.com/specials.php then add classname on HTML body tag == <html><head><body class="classname">content start here....

Answer (score 0):

either the answer by GenericTypeTea

or

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href') == 'http://www.google.com') {
        $(this).addClass('className');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks... but seriously, **never** do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, but I'm still lost where the script above add 'className' on the page. I added the script above on the header of my page and I don't see the 'className' anywhere on the page or on the URL?

Comment: @Mali The CSS class `className` is added to the `<a>` elements. Consider using a DOM inspector like Firebug. Also, see my comment on @GenericTypeTea's answer.